# Thread Not Starting in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to get a thread to run in the following unfinished code.  The basics of which are as follows;  when the console app starts, it should start a thread which will go off, navigate to a web page (which will eventually do some processing) before stopping and killing off the separate thread.  In conjunction, the main application will just provide a menu to the user until the app is exited.  Eventually the navigation thread will be put into a separate method so that it is periodically called every so often but this should not be relevant to this question, I don't think...

My understanding is that the separate thread should just run alongside the main console application and terminate when it has completed its task just like a console would if you don't prevent it exiting?????
What it actually looks like is that it is not starting in the first place as I get no response by way of the browser_DocumentCompleted event triggering (I know the IP address is alive and active, as I've checked!!)

Can anyone shed any light on why the separate thread is not running, or appears not to be?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleThreadTest
{
class Program
{
    public delegate void Callback(string Status);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        NavigateToIPAddress GEIPA = new NavigateToIPAddress(new Uri("http://192.168.1.254"), new Callback(ResultCallback));
        Thread PerformThreadTask = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GEIPA.PerformThreadTask));
        PerformThreadTask.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        PerformThreadTask.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("{0}","Press escape key to exit");

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                switch (key.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        //Kill off thread if it is still running.
                        if (PerformThreadTask.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
                        {
                            PerformThreadTask.Abort();
                        }
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void ResultCallback(string Status)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"), Status);
    }

    public class NavigateToIPAddress
    {
        private Uri WebAddress;
        private bool WebBrowserNavigationComplete = false;

        // Delegate used to execute the callback method when the task is complete.
        private Callback callback;

        // The constructor obtains the state information and the callback delegate.
        public NavigateToIPAddress(Uri IPAddressToNavigateTo, Callback callbackDelegate)
        {
            WebAddress = IPAddressToNavigateTo;
            callback = callbackDelegate;
        }

        // The thread procedure performs the task and then invokes the callback delegate with the status.
        public void PerformThreadTask()
        {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            try
            {
                br.Navigate(WebAddress);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\tSome error occurred: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"), e.Message);
            }

            Application.Run();

            while (WebBrowserNavigationComplete == false)
            {
            }

            if (callback != null)
                callback("Summit occurred");
        }

        private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var br = sender as WebBrowser;
            if (br.Url == e.Url)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\tNavigated to {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"), e.Url);
                WebBrowserNavigationComplete = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here I have a catch 22 situation.  On one hand, if I leave the code as is above, anything after the `application.run()` method does not get executed which means the WebBrowserNavigationComplete flag will never change and the callback will never be returned.
If however I move `application.run()` after

```
if (callback != null)
  callback("Summit occurred");
```

the code will never reach this point in order to call `application.run()` as it is stuck in the while loop waiting for the WebBrowserNavigationComplete flag which will never change as the message loop is never started!!

I cannot believe I am the first to do anything like this?  What is the normal way to overcome this deadlock?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`WebBrowser` is a winforms construct, and requires an application loop be set up to process messages for it.  Since you have a console application and no message loop, it won't function properly.

You'll need to explicitly create a new application loop using `Application.Run` (which needs to be run from an STA thread) for it to work.

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion.  I've edited the code above and added the 'Application.Run()' method in however there is no change and it still functions the same as before. I am however thinking that it is in the wrong place within the thread???  Cannot seem to find out much info other than what it is for on the MSDN website!!

Comment: @cosmarchy `Application.Run` does not return until you exit the application, and you never exit the application, so it will never return, and will never run any of the code following it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand about it not returning until you exit the application.  I have edited my original post and have changed the location of the `Application.Run` which seems to work however I don't understand why....

Comment: @cosmarchy When you call `Application.Run` it starts a message loop and starts processing messages it gets.  It will never return until you send it the message to exit the application.  So you're starting the application, sending it no messages, so it's just sitting there waiting to be told what to do.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the explanation :)